# Inserting a block in a CMS page between content heading and content

Tags: blocks, cms, xml

I am trying to add a custom block on all CMS pages after the page's Content Heading but before the page's Content.

For reference, this is what is in my theme's **layout/cms.xml**, I haven't touched it:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
    <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

The content of **cms/content_heading.phtml** is just this (the heading, as expected), again, haven't touched it:

```
<?php if($_heading = $this->getContentHeading()): ?>
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $_heading; ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In my **local.xml** file, I am adding this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.new.block" after="page_content_heading" template="callouts/my_new_block.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

This is putting the block below the Content Heading AND the Content of the page.

I have also tried this (adding "before" tag):

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.new.block" before="cms_wrapper" after="page_content_heading" template="callouts/my_new_block.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

This is the same as above.

What am I missing? Thanks very much for any help.

(FYI, I am flushing my cache regularly. I'm using Magento 1.8.1)

Comment: try to disable Magento cache entirely and remove cache folder  `magento-root/var/cache`

Comment: I have tried both of those suggestions too, the cache is not the problem because the changes I am making are having an effect, just not the effect I'd like!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `root` block between `label` and `content`? As follows:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/template" name="my_header" as="my_header" template="cms/default/my_header.phtml" />
</reference>
```

So, for clarity:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
    <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
    <!-- ROOT BLOCK HERE -->
    <reference name="content">
        ....
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

This block can be called in the view using `getChildHtml('my_header')`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, can I ask which template file you would suggest I put `getChildHtml('my_header')` in?

Comment: @Sarah That depends on your theme, you could go for `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms/content_heading.phtml`?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably past this issue by now or at least, I'd hope so, but for anyone else who happens upon this post when looking for an answer to the same question, here is one option.

Instead of referencing `content`, reference `cms.wrapper` instead. Then use the before attribute with `cms_page` as the value.  Your block will be inside of the div tag with the std class, but will be above all the other content within that tag.

```
<default>
    <reference name="cms.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.new.block" before="cms_page" template="callouts/my_new_block.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```